# If two maps induce the same homomorphism on the fundamental group, then they are homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

This is exercise 15.11(d) in C. Kosniowsky book *A first course in algebraic topology*:

> Prove that two continuous mappings  $\varphi,\ \psi:X\to Y$, with $\varphi(x_0)=\psi(x_0)$ for some point $x_0\in X$, induce the same homomorphism from $\pi(X,x_0)$ to $\pi(Y,\varphi(x_0))$ if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are homotopic relative to $x_0$.

Which is easy to solve. We were asked to prove the converse but, is it true to begin with? If so, is it an standar exercise or thought one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider $\phi\colon S^2\to S^2$ the identity map.

Comment: Any function is homotopic to itself, so I don't follow you. Is it the converse false?

Comment: What is the induced map and what is *another* obvious function with the same induced map?

Comment: The identity induces the identity homomorphism. The other one is not so obvious to me...

Comment: What is $\pi(S^2)$?

Comment: The trivial one! So the thing is fid another continuous map which is not homotopic to the identity map.

Comment: Right! It's hard for me to guess how much you know.

Comment: I think the constant map should work but I've been thinking for a while trying to figure out why a constant map can not be homotopic to the identity map, without succes...

Comment: Good intuition. You probably need more tools, e.g., homology, to show that $S^2$ is not contractible.

Comment: That's why. Homology is supposed to be for the last exam. I'm not there yet. However there was an exercise: _prove that a map $f:S^{n-1}\to X$ is null homotopic iff there is a continuous extension of $f$ to the whole ball $B^n$._ from which (just realized) it follows easy that the sphere is not contractible :-)

Comment: Yeah, but how do you prove there's no retraction of $D^3$ to $S^2$?

Comment: Consider an extension $I:D^3\to S^2$ of $id:S^2\to S^2$. In these subsets the topology is the one relative to $\Bbb R^3$, so consider any open subset of $S^2$. Pick $x\in I^{-1}(U)$. Then any ball with center $x$ will contain points of $D^3\setminus I^{-1}(U)$, because $I^{-1}(U)=U\subseteq S^2$. In particular $I^{-1}(U)$ is not open.

Comment: Wait, there is no reason for $I^{-1}(U)=U$

Comment: No, indeed not. I think you'll need either homology or Stokes's Theorem to prove this. Hang in there.